# using object_set in django template

Tags: python, django

I have these models:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
   HeadImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")

class Image(models.Model):
   Image = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")
   Gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name='images')
```

in template i have a gallery object,now I wanna iterate it's image objects:

```
{% for i in gallery.image_set.all %}
    <td><img src="{{MEDIAL_URL}}{{i.Image.url}}" width="200px" height="200px"/></td>
{% endfor %}
```

but when I check rendered HTML,I see it doesn't generate any thing.what's wrong with it?
tnx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you use gallery.image_set.all? Related name for images in your Gallery model is "images".